# Minion Math with LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, unicode-math

I cannot get the font Minion Math to display correctly in LuaLaTeX. Several posts on here and the [official font support page](http://www.typoma.com/en/support.html) all say to use the package `unicode-math`. And so I try:

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}

 \setromanfont{Minion Pro}
 \setmathfont{MinionMath-Regular}

 \begin{document}
 Example math:
 $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2}-3\phi}{2\pi\chi} \left(\frac{1}{x}-3\right)$$
 \end{document}
```

but I end up with

[image: TeX output]

where the symbols are all messed up or not even displayed (e.g. the fraction bar).

Do I need to take any additional steps here? I couldn't find this explained anywhere. [Here is the `\listfiles` log](http://pastebin.com/esXBhSdt).

**EDIT**: Apparently the problem with fractions can be fixed with something like

```
\setmathfont[range={\mathfrak}]{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
```

so it looks like a problem with the font itself. The `\left`-`\right` brackets and integral sign still stay the same size.

Comment: Is `MinionMath-Regular` an OpenType font?

Comment: I can't replicate your problem with current versions of LuaTeX, `unicode-math`, and Minion Math (1.026). What versions are you using?

Comment: @egreg Yes it is.

Comment: @JuraPintar Latest version of `unicode-math`, Minion Math v1.026, LuaTeX v0.76 (from TeX Live 2013). I've tried updating everything to no avail.

Comment: You should probably update to TeX Live 2014. Your MWE works just fine with LuaTeX 0.79.1 and `unicode-math` 0.7f. Do you get the same output with XeLaTeX?

Comment: @JuraPintar Updated to the same versions that you have and the result is the same. Can it be a problem with my fonts, or something? XeLaTeX complains that `Font \l_fontspec_font has only 8 fontdimen parameters.` and I'm unable to get the font to work there.

Comment: I have found that `\setmathfont[range={\mathfrak}]{texgyrepagella-math.otf}` fixes the problem with displaying fractions.

Comment: But then, I think, you are filling those “only 8 fontdimen parameters” with the ones from TeX Gyre Pagella Math.

Comment: i'm not going to lie, i ended up here because i had to see if someone was using `\LaTeX{}` to typeset little pictures of minions, in an effort to teach kids arithmetic.

Comment: As Manuel says, when you remap an alphabet using `range`, this just causes `unicode-math` to use the parameters of the last maths font so invoked. Before we conclude that you've got a corrupt copy of Minion Math, why don't you add `\listfiles` to your preamble and post the log. That way we can make sure that there isn't a difference in our TeX configurations that could still be causing you to have the problem and me not.

Comment: You might also want to purge your LuaTeX font cache first, with `luaotfload-tool --cache=erase`.

Comment: @JuraPintar [Here is the log](http://pastebin.com/esXBhSdt) when compiling the MWE with no additional settings. I'm not really sure what's going on there so I would appreciate any help with that.

Comment: @sps If you look where `\fontdimen` parameters are set, you'll see that several of them are set to zero. The missing fraction line with no space between numerator and denominator is caused by those wrong values. Note that `luaotfload` gets the values from the OpenType font parameters, so the conjecture is that you have a bad copy of Minion Math. What's the output if you use XeLaTeX?

Comment: @egreg As I've said above, XeLaTeX throws the error `Font \l_fontspec_font has only 8 fontdimen parameters` and does not compile.

Comment: @sps A faulty copy of Minion Math would be my guess also at this point. Other than the erroneous fontdimens in your log that egreg pointed out, I can't find any relevant differences in our logs. You can open `MinionMath-Regular.otf` in FontForge and examine the MATH table directly to confirm (all the MathConstants should have non-zero values). And, naturally, contact Johannes Kuester of Typoma to get replacement font files.

Comment: Were there any solutions to this, or?

Answer (score 9):

Your MWE works just fine here, with LuaLaTeX as well as with XeLaTeX. With identical, correctly typeset results.

Obviously you do have a faulty version of Minion Math fonts.
From where did you get the fonts?

Please do send me (as I'm the creator of Minion Math fonts) your font file and your resulting PDF.

[image: MWE typeset with LuaLaTeX and Minion Math]