# Problem with Minion Math

Tags: unicode-math

I'm trying to experiment with `Minion Math` for the first time. Unfortunetly

```
\setmathfont{Minion Math}
```

under XeLaTeX causes the following error which I don't understand:

```
! Font \l_fontspec_font has only 8 fontdimen parameters.
<recently read> \l__um_font 

l.147     \setmathfont{Minion Math}

? h
To increase the number of font parameters, you must
use \fontdimen immediately after the \font is loaded.
```

LuaLaTeX runs fine. Complete set of font commans is as follows:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Corbel}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Myriad Pro}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Minion Math}
```

Log files gives the following information just before the error:

```
\g__fontspec_family_MinionMath_int=\count276
.................................................
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
. 
. Font family 'MinionMath(0)' created for font 'Minion Math' with options
. [Ligatures={TeX},BoldItalicFont={},ItalicFont={},Script=Math,SizeFeatures={{S
ize=10.95-},{Size=8-10.95,Font=Minion
. Math,Style=MathScript},{Size=-8,Font=Minion Math,Style=MathScriptScript}}].
.  
.  This font family consists of the following NFSS series/shapes:
.  
. - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <10.95->"Minion
. Math/OT:script=math;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"<8-10.95>"Minion
. Math/OT:script=math;language=DFLT;+ssty=0;mapping=tex-text;"<-8>"Minion
. Math/OT:script=math;language=DFLT;+ssty=1;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
. - 'bold' (bx/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"Minion
. Math/B/OT:script=math;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'bold small caps'  (bx/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
.................................................
```

What should I change in my source file?

Comment: Have you tried loading [`mathspec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathspec) instead of `unicode-math`? I.e., `\usepackage[<suitable options>]{mathspec}` followed by `\setmathfont{Minion Math}`. The `mathspec` package bills itself as a package that provides "an interface
to select ordinary text fonts for typesetting mathematics with XƎLaTEX". I'm afraid I can't test this suggestion myself, though, as I don't have access to the Minion Math font files.

Comment: The font is probably faulty/incomplete. It has the math script but not the necessary math font table.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Given that [Minion Math](http://www.typoma.com/en/fonts.html) is a commercial font -- the complete set costs almost 700 euros [!] -- it would be rather disappointing, though certainly not unthinkable, if the font files lacked the required math font tables.

Comment: @Mico The web page  ays that the OpenType MATH table is supported since version 1.020, perhaps Igor has an older version.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov -  Following up on Ulrike's comment: What's the version of your Minion Math file(s)?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, yes, I think the font is faulty. I found it on a forum somewhere, don't remember exectly where.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce.  I think you are using a pirated version of Minion Math which is [known to be broken](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234351/minion-math-with-lualatex).

Go and buy the basic set.  See http://typoma.de/en/fonts.html#mnm_pricing for details.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
%\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Corbel} % I don't have this font
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Myriad Pro}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Minion Math}

\begin{document}
Hello world!  $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$
\end{document}
```

[image]